# Why do we need a separate impl for a supertrait

Tags: rust, traits

Reading the [section on Supertraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) in the Advanced Traits chapter in the Rust book. Trying to apply this in a super simple concrete example, there is something I don't understand.

When I define a trait bound/supertrait for some custom trait, I am **forced** to write the implementation of that supertrait for a specific struct in a separate `impl`-block.

This example works:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};

pub trait Person: Display {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}

pub struct Student {
    name: &'static str
}

impl Person for Student {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("Hi, i am {}", self)
    }
}

impl Display for Student {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        return write!(f, "{}", self.name);
    }
}
```

But it fails, if I try to move the `fmt` implementation into the `impl Person` block:

```rust
...

impl Person for Student {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("Hi, i am {}", self)
    }
    
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        return write!(f, "{}", self.name);
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0407]: method `fmt` is not a member of trait `Person`
  --> src/supertrait_question.rs:16:5
   |
16 | /     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
17 | |         return write!(f, "{}", self.name);
18 | |     }
   | |_____^ not a member of trait `Person`

error[E0277]: `Student` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/supertrait_question.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl Person for Student {
   |      ^^^^^^ `Student` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Student`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
note: required by a bound in `Person`
  --> src/supertrait_question.rs:3:19
   |
3  | pub trait Person: Display {
   |                   ^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Person`
```

My question is why?

Since I defined `Display` to be a supertrait of `Person`, an implementation of the `Person` trait **requires** the `Display` trait to be implemented as well. A trait is just a [collection of methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait.html), so I would expect that all methods of the `Person` trait can be implemented in the same block.

The statement *"method `fmt` is not a member of trait `Person`"* seems strange because `Person` has the `Display` trait bound, which means `fmt` **is** a member of `Person`.

This can be further demonstrated by simply *omitting* the `impl Display for Student` block entirely, which causes the compiler to tell me that *"the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Student`"*. So it is impossible to implement `Person`, but **not** to implement `Display`.

I know that the answer may just be *"that is how Rust works"*, but I would like to understand the reason.

Comment: "[...] which means fmt is a member of Person." But it is not, it is a member of `Display` which happens to be the supertrait of `Person`. Traits don't work like classes where you can arbitrarily override the methods of your supertrait. Supertraits only allow you access to their items from the context of your subtrait. That's all. Think of supertraits as syntactic sugar for a trait bound on `Self`, which is what they are.

Comment: @JonasFassbender I know that is not how they work and I was not talking about overrides at all. My question is whether there is a good reason for why they work like this. If a trait is a set of methods, then `A` with supertrait `B` is a superset of the methods in `B`, no?

Comment: See [@ChayimFriedman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75847426/why-do-we-need-a-separate-impl-for-a-supertrait#comment133787670_75847464). I actually believe that syntactic sugar that would allow you to implement supertrait items in your subtrait is only going to be confusing and an anti-pattern in the long run. What about cases where you have multiple supertraits or mutliple subtraits or both? Imagine having to figure out where to look for the implementations in more complex scenarios.

Comment: @JonasFassbender That is exactly my point: If that were possible you would look in **exactly one place** for every trait. With `A: B + C + D`, whenever you want to implement `A` for some type, you **must** implement `B`, `C` and `D` for that type anway, so why not do that in the same block and instead spread the `impl` blocks (potentially) all over the place? And if you want to implement just `B` for some other type, well you can do that too. I really don't understand your point here.

Comment: But what about `A: B` and `C: B`? You'd have to look in `A`, `B` and `C`'s impl blocks for the implementation of `B`'s items.

Comment: @JonasFassbender Good point. I guess in _that_ case a separate `impl` block for `B` would be much clearer. Maybe that is indeed the core argument against this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trait that declares supertraits is merely a trait with constraints, *not* an extension of its supertraits’ interface.

Conceptually, by declaring `trait Tr2: Tr1`, you only say that if a type `T` implements `Tr2`, it must implement `Tr1` as well, but traits `Tr1` and `Tr2` are otherwise completely independent, and each creates a separate namespace for its associated items (methods, associated types, constants, etc.).  Any code using `T` may import and make use of `Tr1`, or `Tr2`, both, or neither; but if it uses only one of them, it should not even have to think about the other existing.

More concretely, by making each trait a separate namespace, Rust avoids the well-known [fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fragile_base_class&oldid=1144976242).  Each trait can define its own operations that are guaranteed not to clash with any other if it has not been specifically imported into the namespace.  It is therefore entirely possible, though perhaps somewhat ill-advised, to write something like this ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f774eb18e6963abe98f824d1c540e67)):

```rust
mod m {
    pub trait Foo {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("foo!"); }
    }
    
    pub trait Bar {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("bar!"); }
    }
    
    pub trait Quux: Foo+Bar {
        fn xyzzy(&self) { println!("quux!"); }
    }
    
    pub struct X;
    impl Foo for X {}
    impl Bar for X {}
    impl Quux for X {}
}

use m::X;

fn main() {
    let x = X;
    { 
        use m::Foo;
        x.xyzzy();  // prints "foo!"
    }
    {
        use m::Quux;
        x.xyzzy();  // prints "quux!"
    }
}
```

Replace `use m::Foo;` with `use m::Bar;` in the above and see how the behaviour changes.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are different traits?

> because `Person` has the `Display` trait bound, which means `fmt` is a member of `Person`.

No, it is not. A supertrait is a *requirement, something you also need to implement*. It is similar to a `where` clause on the trait you need to satisfy, just a bit different. It is not like e.g. a base class in OOP languages, that make the base class part of the base class.

It is a different trait, and needs to be implemented differently. It can have a blanket implementation, and then you don't need to implement it at all.

Of course, it would also be explainable if it would be possible to implement the supertrait's method inside the subtrait, but it would be more of a syntax sugar and not the actual semantics. I vaguely remeber such proposal, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Maybe I am indeed seeing this through an OOP lens, but I would humbly disagree with the blanket statement _"it is a different trait and needs to be implemented differently"_. Again, the rust docs state a supertrait is [_"a superset of another trait"_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/supertraits.html). Also, the fact that there may have been a suggestion for this syntactic change would suggest I have a point in this question, no?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg You can use the supertrait without implementing the subtrait, so yes, they're different traits. This is also how the Rust compiler sees that, from a technical point of view.

Comment: It seems you are purposefully trying to misunderstand me. Maybe you can abstract yourself from "the way it is". I _know_ they are different traits. I am saying there is more to their relationship. The rust documentation is referring to traits as sets of methods. Defining a supertrait is therefore equivalent to defining the trait as a superset of the methods in the supertrait, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg No, not exactly, because traits are not only sets of methods - they are also entities themselves, at least this is the way the language treats them, although it is certainly fine to think of them as just "set of methods".